# netcore 6.0 Include only latest x sub records

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have this statement

```
var myHistoryDevice = _dbContext
    .With<HistoryDevice>()
    .Include(x => x.Contexts)
    .Include(x => x.Diagnostics)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Device_Guid == guid);
```

This is working fine, but i actually only want the latest 5 context records to be loaded and the latest Diagnostics to be loaded from the subqueries.
How can this be achieved with .EFCore 6?

Comment: OrderBy/Skip/Take are supported.

Comment: [Filtered include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include)

Comment: Oder by Date Descending and then use Take(5) instead of FirstOrDefault.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean for latest? Do you mean the latest created record? If so, you can use `.Reverse().Take(5)`.